# Is it possible to add a CustomAction in a SharePoint 2013 Survey Settings menu?

Tags: custom-actions

We have an application deployed on SharePoint 2013. Part of the application adds custom items to the ribbons of lists and libraries and the edit control block of list and library items.

This is the element respobsible for adding the edit control block item:

```
<CustomAction Id="822a4bc9-25d3-4445-9186-248f0b3aa493.CustomSurveyAction"
              RegistrationType="List"
              RegistrationId="102"
              Location="EditControlBlock"
              Sequence="10001"
              Title="Our App">

 <UrlAction Url="~appWebUrl/Pages/Application.aspx?formUrl=/Runtime/Form/Workflows%3FSPSiteURL%3D{HostUrl}&amp;amp;SPListId%3D{ListId}&amp;amp;SPItemId%3D{ItemId}&amp;amp;SPItemUrl%3D{ItemUrl}&amp;amp;Source%3D{Source}" />
</CustomAction>
```

This is the element responsible for adding the ribbon item

```
<CustomAction Id="3bbe7d92-645c-41b3-b436-ac89a8241361.CustomSurveyActionR"
              RegistrationType="List"
              RegistrationId="102"
              Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
              Sequence="10001"
              Title="Our App">
 <CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children">
      <Button Id="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.CustomSurveyActionRButton"
              Alt="Request CustomSurveyActionR"
              Sequence="100"
              Command="Invoke_CustomSurveyActionRButtonRequest"
              LabelText="Request CustomSurveyActionR"
              TemplateAlias="o1"
              Image32by32="_layouts/15/images/placeholder32x32.png"
              Image16by16="_layouts/15/images/placeholder16x16.png" />
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
   <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_CustomSurveyActionRButtonRequest"
                     CommandAction="~appWebUrl/Pages/Application.aspx?formUrl=/Runtime/Form/Workflows%3FSPSiteURL%3D{HostUrl}&amp;amp;amp;SPListId%3D{ListId}&amp;amp;amp;SPItemId%3D{ItemId}&amp;amp;amp;SPItemUrl%3D{ItemUrl}&amp;amp;amp;Source%3D{Source}"/>
  </CommandUIHandlers>
 </CommandUIExtension >
</CustomAction>
```

In the above XML, the `RegistrationId` is set to `102`, which is the Id for a Surveys. The first, used for ECB custom actions, work and places the item in the ECB of a survey response. However, the second, used for Ribbon custom actions, does not since Surveys don't have ribbons.

Now I've been trying to add the item to the Settings menus of a Survey, but I'm not sure if it's even possible. I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802730.aspx) MSDN entry listing the various Locations and GroupIDs (refer to the `Location` and `GroupID` attributes of the `CustomAction` element). So I tried `GroupID="SettingsMenuForSurvey" Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"` since I'm attempting to add the item to the Survey's Settings menu.

However, when Deploying the application (either via VisualStudio or by Publishing it and uploading it manually) I get one of two errors (depending on which Attributes are present in the XML):

- 'GroupID' attribute is not declared
- 'Location' is invalid - The value 'Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu' is invalid according to its datatype

I also tried a couple of other things and came across [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802730.aspx) MSDN entry, but it only lists Locations relevant to Ribbons; there is nothing on Surveys.

Does anyone have more information that might help?

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth SharePoint "Surveys" don't have ribbon menus and have remained unchanged since SharePoint 2007 days. I've never had much luck customizing the UI related to surveys because of this. The closest thing I found to customize is the columns that display in the "All Responses" view by editing the Page > Edit Web Part > Edit the current view. I also noticed the List Item Menu action shows up related to the Response column as it is the main column that has the ellipsis (...) menu.